# jQuery .load for AJAX Content

Tags: jquery, load

I want to make changes to an image which loads via ajax, but the elements I need to access are not present on document ready, so I tried .load, but that doesn't seem to fire. Can I add some sort of "flag" to the loaded content which can then be detected and cause the .load function below to start after the elements are on the page?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.qmn_results_page').load(function(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("jma-chart");console.log('loaded');
    var img = document.getElementById("source");
    img.src = 'http://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/chart-headings.jpg';
    img.height = 1026;
    img.width = 1000;

    //var img = document.getElementById("source");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var str = $('#jma-chart').data('points');
    var quiz_id = $('#jma-chart').data('id');
    var $points = str.split('|');


    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (index = 0; index < $points.length; ++index) {
        $point = $points[index].split(',');
        if (!index) {
            ctx.moveTo($point[0], $point[1]);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo($point[0], $point[1]);
        }

    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    for (index = 0; index < $points.length; ++index) {
        $point = $points[index].split(',');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc($point[0], $point[1], 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();
    }

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: chartscript.charturl,
    data: {
        action: 'jma_save_image',
        imgBase64: dataURL,
        quiz_id: quiz_id

    },
    success: function( $html  ) {

    }
});
});
```

});

page structure (THE RESULTS DIV IS ADDED DYNAMICALLY ON FORM SUBMISSION):

`

`

Comment: Please include your html markup as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the element is not yet present and you want to bind it with an event try using the jquery .on() method. This will attach an event to specific element. You can refer to this documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Tried replacing with:
$(document).on('load', '.qmn_results_page', function(event) {
my stuff
}
no luck

Answer (score 0):

**instead of**

```
$('.qmn_results_page').load(function(event) {
   ...
});
```

**Try this**

```
$(document).on('load', '.qmn_results_page', function(){
  ....
  blah blah blah
  ...

})
```